# custom type_index order without boost

Tags: c++, dictionary, indexing

I have the following map :

```cpp
std::map<std::type_index, std::set<Status *>> statuses;
```

It store sets of the different subclasses of `Status` there, thanks to their `std::type_index`.
However I want to have control about the order of the objects in this map (for instance, I have two classes `Burn` and `Stun` that inherit from `Status`, and I would like `typeid(Stun) < typeif(Burn)` so that when I iterate through the map I get the `std::set<Stun>` before the `std::set<Burn>`).

I thought about implementing a custom `type_index` class but I can't seem to find any way to do this without boost, which is a huge library that I would like not to have to include to my project.

Any advice on how to have a custom order in the map?

Comment: C++ doesn't offer this feature. You'll need to explicitly map each type to it's priority. You'll need to define each type's unique ordering somehow. Since your types are already polymorphic, you can give them a common base type that reports this priority.

Comment: You could use an `enum` instead of `std::type_index`.  Then you can control the sort by controlling the value each enumeration has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `type_index` into a custom type with a comparator that yields the desired order.

The example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) modified using `std::map` rather than `std::unordered_map` and with a custom comparator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
 
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
};
 
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};

struct my_type_index {
    std::type_index index = std::type_index(typeid(void));
    my_type_index() = default;
    my_type_index(std::type_index i) : index(i) {}
    bool operator<(const my_type_index& other) const {
        static std::map< std::type_index,int> rank{
            { std::type_index(typeid(A)) , 1},
            { std::type_index(typeid(B)),  2},
            { std::type_index(typeid(double)),  3},
            { std::type_index(typeid(int)),  4},
            { std::type_index(typeid(C)),  5}
        };        
        return rank[index] < rank[other.index];
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::map<my_type_index, std::string> type_names;
 
    type_names[std::type_index(typeid(int))] = "int";
    type_names[std::type_index(typeid(double))] = "double";
    type_names[std::type_index(typeid(A))] = "A";
    type_names[std::type_index(typeid(B))] = "B";
    type_names[std::type_index(typeid(C))] = "C";
   
    for (const auto& e : type_names) {
        std::cout << e.first.index.name() << " " << e.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/ETM7d5j7c):

```
1A A
1B B
d double
i int
1C C
```

---

With improvements suggested by François Andrieux:

```
struct my_type_index {
    std::type_index index = std::type_index(typeid(void));
    int rank = 0;
    my_type_index() = default;
    my_type_index(std::type_index i) : index(i) {
        auto it = ranks.find(i);
        if (it != ranks.end()) rank = it->second;
    }
    
    static const std::map<std::type_index,int> ranks;
    
    bool operator<(const my_type_index& other) const {        
        return rank < other.rank;
    }
};

const std::map<std::type_index,int> my_type_index::ranks = [](){
    std::map<std::type_index,int> result;
    std::type_index index_order[] = {
        std::type_index(typeid(A)),
        std::type_index(typeid(B)),
        std::type_index(typeid(double)),
        std::type_index(typeid(int)),
        std::type_index(typeid(C)) 
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(index_order);++i){ result[ index_order[i]] = i+1; }
    return result;
}();
```

The ranking is stored in the static map `ranks` and each instances `rank` is already evaluated on construction (instead of on each comparison, ie comparisons are now cheaper). Also the map is now generated from an array, which is more robust (you cannot mistype the index/rank anymore). Further, the map is `const`, ie `find` instead of `operator[]` is used for look up. Elements not in the map will be assigned rank 0. Actually that was also the case before, but before `operator[]` was potentially adding unnecessary elements to the map.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the improvement. As the map `rank` is declared as static in the operator, will it be redeclared on every lookup? also if we remove the declaration from the operator and declare a static map, how is it worse than having this lambda function to construct it? I also have trouble understanding how this function will be called (only once as it is static ? when constructing the first type_index object or at compilation?)

Comment: @startresse when it is static it is initialized only once. The first version makes a lookup in the map for every single comparison. The second version makes a lookup in the map only once when the object is constructed, and then on comparing only compares two integers. The lambda is only called once to construct the static member.